# Не пойму почему не работает путь к .js

Tags: javascript, html5

В браузере отображает ошибку:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeUp = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();

bird.src = "img/bird.png";
bg.src = "img/bg.png";
fg.src = "img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "img/pipeBottom.png";


var gap = 90;

// При нажатии на какую-либо кнопку
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveUp);

function moveUp() {
  yPos -= 25;
  fly.play();
}

// Создание блоков
var pipe = [];

pipe[0] = {
  x: cvs.width,
  y: 0
}

var score = 0;
// Позиция птички
var xPos = 10;
var yPos = 150;
var grav = 1.5;

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(pipeUp, pipe[i].x, pipe[i].y);
    ctx.drawImage(pipeBottom, pipe[i].x, pipe[i].y + pipeUp.height + gap);

    pipe[i].x--;

    if (pipe[i].x == 125) {
      pipe.push({
        x: cvs.width,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * pipeUp.height) - pipeUp.height
      });
    }

    // Отслеживание прикосновений
    if (xPos + bird.width >= pipe[i].x &&
      xPos <= pipe[i].x + pipeUp.width &&
      (yPos <= pipe[i].y + pipeUp.height ||
        yPos + bird.height >= pipe[i].y + pipeUp.height + gap) || yPos + bird.height >= cvs.height - fg.height) {
      location.reload(); // Перезагрузка страницы
    }

    if (pipe[i].x == 5) {
      score++;
      score_audio.play();
    }
  }

  ctx.drawImage(fg, 0, cvs.height - fg.height);
  ctx.drawImage(bird, xPos, yPos);

  yPos += grav;

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.font = "24px Verdana";
  ctx.fillText("Счет: " + score, 10, cvs.height - 20);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

pipeBottom.onload = draw;
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
```

Comment: какой именно файл не найден? в ошибке указывается путь по которому был поиск - по этому пути есть файл?

Comment: да файл game.js

Comment: я похоже что-то сильно не понимаю :)

Comment: можете сказать что мне посмотреть/почитать чтоб разобраться или я могу сделать скрин екрана з ошибкой

Comment: во вкладке network (сеть) запрос к файлу будет выделен красным. Нажми на этот запрос и посмотри значение `Request URL:` во вкладке Headers

Comment: file:///C:/Users/911/Desktop/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%802/game%20dump/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80/js/game.js путь по  якому не получается найти файл

Comment: C:\Users\911\Desktop\програмирование вер2\game dump\пример  //расположение файла

Comment: так, расположение `\game dump\пример` а ищешь ты в `\game dump\пример\js` - поэтому и не находит же. Попробуй тут: `<script src="js/game.js"></script>` заменить на `<script src="game.js"></script>`

Comment: огромное спасибо ( не подажете как можно  поставить метку что уже есть ответ на вопрос ?)